Confusion with metpy water vapor functions
I'm trying to solve for surface turbulent latent heat flux and I need surface saturation humidity (qs) and surface air humidity (qa)
I currently have the 2m dew point temperature and 2m temperature from the ERA5 dataset.
If what I'm thinking is correct, surface saturation humidity (qs) is just the specific humidity at the dew point. I therefore used metpy's specific_humidity_from_dewpoint function.
But isn't the specific humidity at the dew point also just the saturation mixing ratio at the dew point? I used metpy's saturation_mixing_ratio function but it gave me a ever so slightly different result from the first one.
I'm also trying to solve for the surface air humidity. I thought of doing relative_humidity_from_dewpoint, mixing_ratio_from_relative_humidity, and then finally specific_humidity_from_mixing_ratio
Am I doing this correctly?
